# Как узнать общее кол-во созданных документов в коллекции mongodb за всё время?

Tags: mongodb

Есть ли возможность **стандартными** средствами mongodb, **без** создания специального поля счетчика, узнать **общее кол-во** уже созданных документов в коллекции **за всё время жизни** данной коллекции?

**Пример:**

- В новой коллекции добавим 2 произвольных документа.
- Один из них удалим.
- Необходим метод который вернет число 2 (Т.е кол-во созданных
  документов за всё время)

Понятно что можно создать отдельное поле для этих целей. Но возможно ли добиться этого стандартным функционалом mongodb?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно использовать метод [`count()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) если вы хотите знать кол-во документы в коллекции

```
db.collection.count()
```

Но нет никакого способа знать кол-во созданных за всё время жизни коллекции, в том числе те, которые были удалены.

Answer (score 0):

я в java посчитал так:

```
collection.countDocuments();
```